# Centering div after resize with even space?

Tags: html, css, center

Hello i am having a problem with get the elements inside a centered div to appear in center with horizontal space being even between the left and right side.

The problem isn't centering the div but maintaining the space even with the limits when the window is too small (ex: Smartphone) and since the page is expected to be responsive and load on any screen i would like for it to be even.
This is how the **HTML** code looks:

```
<body>
<div class="header">
<h1 align="center">CRM</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-m-12">
<div class="row"> 
<div id="group1">       
    <div class="tile amarelo" onclick="location.href='http://stackoverflow.com/'">
    <span class="titulo">Calendar Placeholder</span><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="tile azul">
    <span class="titulo">Budget Placeholder</span><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="tile azul">
    <span class="titulo">Program X</span><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="tile azul">
    <span class="titulo">Program Y</span><br/>
    </div>
    </div>  

    <div id="group2"> 
    <div class="tile azul">
    <span class="titulo">Program W</span><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="tile azul">
    <span class="titulo">Program Z</span><br/>  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
/* For tablets: */
.col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/* For desktop: */
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

}
[class*="col-"] {
margin:0 auto;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.da{
background-color:#FF0000;

}

.db{background-color:#0101DF;}
.hide{
 display:none;
  }

 .row:after {
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 display: block;
 }



 body{
 font-family: Calibri;
 background: rgb(51,51,51);
 color: #fff;
 }

.row{
width:auto;
padding:5px;
height:auto;
display:table; 
margin:0 auto;     
 }

 .tile{

cursor:pointer;
height:110px;   
width:110px;  
float:left;
margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
padding:2px;
}

.amarelo{
background:#DAA520;
}

.azul{
background:#4682B4;
}

.header {
background-color: #58D3F7;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 15px;
}
```

I have created a fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/DiogoSilva/ojnkbzbd/1/

What happens is when i resize the window the elements go to the left and the right limit is bigger than the left one.

**EDIT:**

Printscreen added : http://s8.postimg.org/yo55yy1wl/crm_Bug.jpg

**SOLUTION 1:**

From the chosen answer i was able to achieve what i envisioned which was have the smartphone tiles centered similar to windows phone and in tablet screens and desktop screens having the elements floating left.

**CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
/* For tablets: */
.col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
.tile-M{
cursor:pointer;
height:110px;   
width:110px;  
float:left;
display:inline-block;
margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
padding:2px;
}

.row-M{
width:auto;
padding:5px;
height:auto;
display:table; 
margin:0 auto;     

}

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/* For desktop: */
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}
.tile-D{
cursor:pointer;
height:110px;   
width:110px;  
float:left;
display:inline-block;
margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
padding:2px;
 }

  .row-D{
  width:auto;
  padding:5px;
  height:auto;
  display:table; 
  margin:0 auto;     

 }
 }
 [class*="col-"] {
 margin:0 auto;
 border: 1px solid red;
 }
.da{
background-color:#FF0000;

}

.db{background-color:#0101DF;}



.hide{
display:none;
}

.row:after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: block;
}



body{
font-family: Calibri;
background: rgb(51,51,51);
color: #fff;
}

.row{

width:auto;
padding:5px;
height:auto;
display:table; 
margin:0 auto;     
text-align:center;


}

.tile{

cursor:pointer;
height:110px;   
width:110px;  
display: inline-block;
overflow: auto;
margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
padding:2px;
text-align:left;



 }

 .amarelo{
 background:#DAA520;
 }

 .azul{
 background:#4682B4;
 }

.header {
background-color: #58D3F7;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 15px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js">     </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/mainMenu.js"></script>
 <title>CRM</title>
 </head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<h1 align="center">CRM</h1>
</div>
<div id="conteudo" class="col-12 col-m-12">
<div class="row row-D row-M"> 
<div id="group1">       
    <div id="tile" class="tile tile-D tile-M amarelo">
     <a href="Calendar/calendar.jsp"></a> 
    <span class="titulo">Calendar Placeholder</span><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="tile tile-D tile-M azul">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"></a> 
    <span class="titulo">Budget Placeholder</span><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="tile tile-D tile-M azul">
    <span class="titulo">Program X</span><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="tile tile-D tile-M azul">
    <span class="titulo">Program Y</span><br/>
    </div>
    </div>  

    <div id="group2"> 
    <div class="tile tile-D tile-M azul">
    <span class="titulo">Program W</span><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="tile tile-D tile-M azul">
    <span class="titulo">Program Z</span><br/>  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams your `float:left;` is crushing the centering.

You can try using `text-align:center;` on your `.row` and `display:inline-block;`, `overflow:auto;` and `text-align:left;` on your `.tile` to center your boxes:

```
.row{
    width:auto;
    padding:5px;
    height:auto;
    display:table; 
    margin:0 auto;     
    text-align:center;
}
.tile{
    cursor:pointer;
    height:110px;   
    width:110px;  
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding:2px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Please bare in mind that a new `#groupN` will always start a new row.

Please see this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ojnkbzbd/4/)**

Comment: it works as intended although now it always centers the elements but i think i can solve it by having the css apply the float:left when the window reaches a certain size

Comment: i managed to achieve the intended result with a few tweaks thank you...i will update my code in the post

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want?

```
.tile{
    cursor:pointer;
    height:110px;   
    width:110px;  
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding:2px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DiogoSilva/ojnkbzbd/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i had already tried that and it didn't work i'll take a print screen and put it in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

You'll see I've made the following changes:

```
.tile{
    cursor:pointer;
    height:110px;   
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    margin:5px 0;
    padding:2px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .tile {width: 48%; margin:5px 1%; padding: 10px;} 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .tile {max-width:31%;} 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .tile {max-width:23%;} 
}
```

Please see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ojnkbzbd/2/), I've added the red background to the .row container for the example. I've also removed `<div class="col-12 col-m-12">` from your HTML as I wasn't sure what this conainter was doing but you may need to add that back in as I was only focusing on the child containers stacking for this example.

Comment: i have tried it and it works but changing the tile size isn't an option i'm afraid... thank you for your answer tough but i have a solution now